# Angular 2 relative paths with webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have a simple component that works  fine:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `./src/app/app.component.html`,
  styleUrls: ['./src/app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {  }
```

The problem is the paths are absolute. I changed it to this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `./app.component.html`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {  }
```

And it gives me an error:

> GET http://localhost:7000/app.component.html 404 (Not Found)

The question is how can I use relative paths with webpack (moduleId: module.id is not working here) without third-part loaders or stuff like:

```
template: require('...')
```

By the way I`m using webpack 2.2.1 with this loaders:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                include: srcPath,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', { "modules": false }],
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    optional: 'runtime'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out with angular 2 template loader?  I am wondering if you changed 'templateUrl' to 'template'  and had to remove './'

Comment: I was using templates like this: templateUrl: 'main.component.html' for the file in the same filder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you will have to use another third party loader. I used angular2-template-loader in a recent project to get webpack to load our templates.

https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader